# Html code shows when browse the home.aspx

Tags: asp.net, html, iis-7, web, windows-server-2008-r2

I have windows server 2008 R2 and IIS 7 to host the website. When I create the virtual directory and set the default document say **Home.aspx** and host the site. When I browse the page it shows the home page's html code. I have test this many times but same issue. Any thing wrong in my code aur any issue in hosting the site. Pls do the needfull.

Thanks

Dinesh Kumar

Comment: Is IIS setup to execute .NET code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IIS is not setup to use .NET.

You can install .NET on IIS by going to the framework directory of the version you are using (`%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v.XXXXXX`) and executing `aspnet_regiis.exe`.

Comment: I could not under stand what do you want to say. Pls explain this

Comment: @Dinesh - What don't you understand?

Comment: Oh.... Now I understood. Actually I have installed IIS after .net 3.5. So .net application shows html code in browser. Is there any other way to install IIS 7 again without uninstalling visual studio 2008?

Comment: @Dinesh - You don't need to reinstall IIS 7. Just run `aspnet_regiis` as I have described in my answer.